# How to recover encrypted/locked volume on M1 Mac with recovery key, missing password?

Tags: recovery, encryption, filevault, apple-silicon, disk-volume

I set up my new M1 Macbook Pro about 3 months ago and made a separate volume for safekeeping things inside. This volume shows up in Disk Utility, described as **"APFS Volume, APFS (Encrypted)"**

I have used the computer since then without rebooting, just going into sleep mode when not used. Today I rebooted for the first time and was locked out of this encrypted Volume. I can log into OSX as usual and I can use everything else normally, I just can't access the encrypted volume.

After logging in, I'm asked for a password to unlock the volume, but I don't have the password.

I've done some reading and understood that it's possible to use a recovery key. I've found such a key that I wrote down on the same day I set up this volume. But I don't know what to do with the key. How to make use of it?
The format of the key is ABCD-ABCD-ABCD-ABCD-ABCD-ABCD.

I've tried the recovery mode where pressing the startup button for a while gets a menu with "Options" , but once in there, I only get to choose which of the volumes to recover, and it's again asking for a password, not for a recovery key. So the Recovery Mode was not very helpful.

Comment: Did you try entering the recovery key (with dashes) in the password prompt? This says it should accept it : https://www.ufsexplorer.com/articles/how-to/recover-data-apfs-encryption.php

Comment: @lx07 I tried that and it did not work. I gave up in the end and luckily didn't have anything that I couldn't recreate on the encrypted volume.